# Possible to install a VS 2010 extension in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

There is [this VSIX extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a63745c0-a781-48fa-a7d2-573ee80b5d7e) that I would love to have in Visual Studio 2013.

Unfortunately it refuses to install, since it is only for Visual Studio 2010:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

**My question:**

Any chance to trick VS 2013 into at least *trying* to install the extension?

Comment: If there is source code available, you could try to recompile it for vs2013. Current version won't work, as it uses dll from vs2010

Answer (score 2):

I found out that a VSIX is acutally just a ZIP file.

Inside the ZIP file there is an "extension.vsixmanifest" file. This XML file contains something like

```
<VisualStudio Version="10.0">
```

So I opened the VSIX file with 7-Zip, edited the manifest and changed "10.0" to "12.0".

After these steps, I succeeded installing the extension.

It even appears correctly in the "Extensions and Updates" window in Visual Studio.